# Connect react js and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, http

I'm completely new to node js. Trying to implement registration form with react and send user data to the server. When trying to make a post request to node js, a new user is created, but all of his fields are undefined. On the front side, when fetching post request, I can get current user with fetch.then(), but it's fields also undefined.
What could be the problem?

```
const Form = () => {

const [users, setUsers] = useState({
    emails: [],
    usernames: []
});

useEffect( () => {
    async function fetchAPI() {
        let response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000');
        response = await response.json()
        setUsers(response);
    }
    fetchAPI();
}, [])

const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

const submit = () => {
    let state = {
        username,
        email,
        password,
        confirmPassword,
        auth: true
    }

    if (!(usernameError || emailError || passwordError || confirmPasswordError)) {

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/users_api', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application.json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(state)
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
    }
}

return (
    <div className={classes.item}>
        <Input errorMessage='username is incorrect'
               inputType='username'
               handleInput={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
               value={username}/>
        <Input errorMessage='email is not valid'
               inputType='email'
               handleInput={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
               value={email}/>
        <Input errorMessage='password is incorrect'
               inputType='password'
               handleInput={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
               value={password}/>
        <Input errorMessage="passwords don't match"
               inputType='password'
               password={password}
               handleInput={e => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
               value={confirmPassword}/>
        <button onClick={submit}>Register</button>
    </div>
);
};
```

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

let users = [];

app.post('/users_api', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = {
        username: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
        auth: req.body.auth
    }

    users = [...users, newUser];
    res.setHeader('users', users)
    res.send({users: users})
    console.log(users);
})

app.get('/users_api', (req, res) => {
    res.send({express: 'connected'})
})

require('./routes/index')(app);
```

Comment: I am not sure if there's no other problems, but `application.json` is not a valid content type, it should be `application/json`

Comment: @ncpa0cpl that was the whole problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your fetch method, instead of

```
'Content-Type': 'application.json'
```

Try this

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```